# How to change the label of the "To:" field in the Date Module

Tags: 7, theming, forms, datetime

This doesn't seem to be the kind of thing you can change using `hook_form_alter()` unless I'm missing something.

The label of the "From" field can be any value you want, but the "to" field, if you have one, defaults to "to", see `modules/date/date_elements.inc`, line 369:

```
    $element[$to_field]['#title'] = t('to:');
```

so what's the correct way to change that to a value of my choosing, i.e. "Expires"? Via the Theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look further on down in `date_elements.inc` at line 412 you'll notice:

```
drupal_alter('date_combo_process', $element, $form_state, $context);
```

which allows any module to [alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/drupal_alter/7) what it's created, eg, something like this:

```
function YOURMODULE_date_combo_process_alter(&$element, &$form_state, &$context) {

  $element['value2']['#title'] = t('expires:'); // this will change that to: to expires:

}
```

Just realize this simple example will do this for every instance of a combination to/from date, but information to get more specific is contained in `$element`, `$form_state` and `$context`.  For example, the specific field name is contained in `$element['#field_name']` and the form_id is in `$form_state['build_info']['form_id']`.

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. Just for the record, is it unusual for the Date module's forms to work this way? Providing their own method of changing the module's forms because it's not accessible via `form_alter` ?

Comment: They are both alters, eg, `MODULE_TYPE_alter()`, so `MODULE_form_alter()` and `MODULE_date_combo_process_alter()` both allow modules to alter something another module has created, eg, the date and form modules.  In this case, they are just nested, so you need to alter the piece created by the right module. BTW, @xurshid29's answer below works as well; just another example of how extensible and in many ways Drupal is.

Answer (score 1):

I always do this kind of thing with `hook_form_alter()` and `pre_render` function: example:

```
function MY_MODULE_OR_THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'MY_FORM_ID') {
   $form['#pre_render'][] = 'MY_CUSTOM_pre_render';
  }
}

function MY_CUSTOM_pre_render($element) {
  //dpm($form);
  //$element['MY_FIELD_NAME']['max']['#title'] = t('MY NEW TITLE'); // Find your proper field element.
  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a module named [String Overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) that lets you override any string that is inserted via the `t()` function.  You should be able to use that to module override "to:".